# A question about the proof of Rado's Theorem in Rudin's Real and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

In Rudin's book "Real and Complex Analysis",third edition,p. 263, the author gave the following theorem

> Assume $f\in C(\bar{U})$,$\Omega$ is the set of all $z\in U$ at which $f(z)\neq 0$,and $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.Then $f$ is holomorphic in $U$.

In the proof, Rudin assume $\Omega \neq \varnothing$,and first prove that $\Omega$ is dense in $U$.There it says that if  $\Omega$ is not dense,then

> ***there exist $\alpha \in \Omega$ and $\beta \in U\backslash
> \bar{\Omega}$ such that $2|\beta-\alpha|<1-|\beta|$.***

I wonder how to get the conclusion the above line says.What I can see is that $\Omega$ is an open subset of $U$,and $U\backslash \bar{\Omega}$ is open and not empty. I'd appreciate it if you could give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z \in \partial (U\setminus \overline{ \Omega})$. [What happens if there is no such $z$? Do you see the contradiction to connectedness of $U$?].Then there exist sequence $(\alpha_n) \subset \Omega$, $(\beta_n)\subset U\setminus \overline {\Omega}$ such that they both converge to $z$. Now check that the inequality holds with $\alpha=\alpha_n, \beta=\beta_n$ with $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Yes it's true if $z\in \partial \Omega \cap U$,but when $z\in \partial \Omega\cap \partial U$,$1-|\beta_n|\to 0$,$n\to \infty$.

Comment: Maybe I should first prove $\partial \Omega \cap U\neq \varnothing$,then the question is done.Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @mbfkk $1-|\beta_n| \to 1-|z| >0$.  ($z$ is not in the boundary of $U$. It is in the boundary of $\Omega$). Since $U$ is connected any subset of it has non-empty boundary in $U$.

Comment: Thanks,I think I get it !$U=\Omega \cup (\partial \Omega\cap U)\cup (U\backslash \bar{\Omega})$,If $\partial \Omega \cap U= \varnothing$,then $U$ is the union of two  noempty open set,a controdiction to the fact that $U$is connected. so we can choose $z\in \partial \Omega \cap U$ to solve the problem.

Comment: Why $\beta_n \in U - \bar{\Omega}$ ? By definition, we can only know that $\beta_n \in U - \Omega$ and in general $\partial \bar{\Omega} \subset \partial \Omega$

Comment: @Jiya I have modified the argument.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, if the boundary of $U - \bar\Omega = \emptyset$ then $U - \bar\Omega$ is closed, while clearly open so contradicting to connectedness.. thank you for your kind reply